# What is the proper term for magic cast from material components

Tags: magic, terminology

I am working on a setting for an RPG and I am trying to research proper **terminology** for different kinds of magic.

I would like to know what the proper name is for magic cast explicitly from objects. These objects are **required** for the magic to be performed. An example could be the use of a voodoo doll where any harm done to the doll is also done to a particular person. Or perhaps being able to see distant places through the use of a crystal ball or a mirror. The magic simply can not work without a particular implement.

Through my research I have so far identified the following 'kinds' of magic:

- Theurgy - magical abilities given to a character by a mystical entity. (a deity, a demon, faeries, etc) Think clerics or warlocks from D&D
- Thaumaturgy - your classical wizard / mage casting spells through sigils, formulas and magic words
- Psionics - supernatural spell-like abilities created through the power of the mind

So what would you suggest I call this elusive fourth kind of magic? I would much prefer something vaguely latin or greek that fits well with the other terms.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi DudeDoesThings! I'm not sure your example types of magic are completely accurate. It's not clear if this is for a specific RPG but you seem to reference D&D. If that's the case, it's not clear to me that arcane magic isn't [sourced from a god](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103779/48793) (or, at least, related to the activity of gods). Also, it seems that there are different kinds of magic/items too: an arcane focus like a crystal ball works differently than a vessel that always refills its liquid, etc.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. This kind of question is a matter of opinion. Magic terminology varies by setting and culture, so it's hard to measure which suggested names are valid or supported. If you're the designer of this RPG, then ultimately the names are up to you. Perhaps with more research you can find or create a name you like.

Comment: Is this maybe a question better suited the world-building stack?

Comment: Yes this would possibly be a better fit for [Worldbuilding StackExchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Okay, I will ask the question over at Worldbuilding. Thanks.

Comment: I am having trouble with sources at the moment, but I think you are looking at a versino of sympathetic magic, see you over at Worldbuilding.

Comment: @MikeQ Just an FYI, one of the Worldbuilding.SE mods said that this may be too primarily opinion-based for their site, so we're not going to migrate it. OP can still try to ask it there manually, but if people think that  we can answer it here (maybe with an edit) it might be fine here as well.